# How can i set my vm to have exclusive access to my ethernet port in mac os x lion?

Tags: windows-7, vmware, osx-lion, ifconfig

I have a vmware of windows 7 on osx lion. I am on a corporate network that assigns IPs via DHCP through ethernet, and i also have an airport card thats connected to a 4g hotspot.

This corporate network is behind a proxy and what i need to be able to do is force osx lion to use my airport and force vmware to use the ethernet.

I have set the network priority order under preferences -> network -> advanced but is there anything else i need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forced my mac to use Wifi as the preferred method, then in vmware options i set the network adapter to ethernet. Enabled proxy settings in my vmware and its functioning properly.